# How to use odo to save incoming websocket data to MySQL using Python 2?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Using Windows 7, and python 2.
Novice programmer, but learning fast!

I'm currently rewriting my code to save incoming websocket data from poloniex.com to a MySQL Database. I receive about 200-300 messages a second. Previously I was using MySQLDB module and the executemany statement for bulk inserts where possible.

I need to improve efficiency to scale better when I begin pulling data from more sites. After some research I found odo, but I haven't been able to figure out to use it in my case, or if i even can.

My question is:

Do I have to put the incoming data into a csv file then use odo to move it into my db? What would the workflow look like with that? Would I append the messages from my websocket to the end of a csv file and pull from the top with odo? Or is there possibly a way to take the messages directly and feed them to MySQL using odo without first moving it to a csv file?

And then my last concern, I've tried using text files when figuring out my db the first time, and it was way slow. Would going to csv file, then going to mysql using odo really be faster than my next best option, using pandas?

Comment: MySQL can easy import a CVS file into a table..  The query looks something like `LOAD DATA INFILE '[path_to_cvs_file]' 
INTO TABLE [table]
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;`..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to loan my incoming websocket messages to a csv file, and I'm having a hard time figuring out the right workflow to accomplish this. Would I convert a list of messages to a csv file every second, or work with one csv file, appending messages to the end? And then, will working thru a csv file be faster than using pandas to mysql? Also, I'm working thru a Python 2 script, not directly with mysql.

Comment: i know you need to have a websocket server to handle the websockets. Why not keeping the data in the memory? And every minute export the memory data into a `INSERT INTO table ([columns]) VALUE ([values]), ([values])` (multi insert)  query and execute it on MySQL... memory acces is much faster when working with files